# Insert Left Join SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with the following SQL

I have two tables `titles` and `postcode_db` I want to LEFT JOIN and INSERT into a third table

```
SELECT titles.id, titles.title, titles.address, 
postcode_db.postcode, postcode_db.suburb
FROM titles
LEFT JOIN postcode_db ON titles.address = postcode_db.suburb;
```

Above works.  I want to insert into `titles_postcode`

`titles.id AS titles_postcode.title_id`

`titles.title AS titles_postcode.title`

`postcode_db.postcode`

```
INSERT INTO titles_postcode 
(titles.id AS titles_postcode.title_id, 
titles.title AS titles_postcode.title, 
postcode_db.postcode AS titles_postcode.postcode)
SELECT titles.id, titles.title, titles.address, 
postcode_db.postcode, postcode_db.suburb
FROM titles
LEFT JOIN postcode_db ON titles.address = postcode_db.suburb;
```

Its returning `error right syntax to use near 'AS titles_postcode.title_id, titles.title AS titles_postcode.title, postcode_db.' at line 1`

Comment: I think the error is self-explaining: don't use alias. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO titles_postcode (title_id, title, postcode)
SELECT titles.id, titles.title, postcode_db.postcode
FROM titles
LEFT JOIN postcode_db ON titles.address = postcode_db.suburb;
```

Comment: Column doesnt match value count

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use alias in your insert query and also your values doesn't match column count, i asssume you only need those 3 columns to be inserted

```
INSERT INTO titles_postcode  (title_id, title, postcode)
SELECT titles.id, titles.title, postcode_db.postcode
FROM titles
LEFT JOIN postcode_db 
ON titles.address = postcode_db.suburb;
```

Comment: @KevinBowersox Not in a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT...` form.

Comment: @stephenmelb you are welcome man, if you feel my answer was correct and helped you out you might consider accepting it so you will also help people in the future with similar problems.  To accept you just need to click on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO titles_postcode(title_id,title,postcode) 
SELECT titles.id, titles.title, titles.address, 
postcode_db.postcode
FROM titles
LEFT JOIN postcode_db ON titles.address = postcode_db.suburb;
```